# solving exponential equations giving the answer is the form $\log_e(a)/\log_e(b)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

I'm having trouble with this question as my teacher didn't quite explain it well. I understand you have to change it to log form and bring the exponent to the front but I'm not sure what I do after that. [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are very nearly there, though you need to be careful with your parentheses.  You should currently have:
$$(3-2x)\log_{e}5=(1+x)\log_{e}2.$$  Remember that $\log_{e}5$ and $\log_{e}2$ are just numbers, so you should treat them as any other numbers in an equation.  At this point you have an equation with $x$ on both sides, so your next steps are to distribute through the parentheses:
$$3\log_{e}5-(2\log_{e}5)x = \log_{e}2+(\log_{e}2)x.$$  I added the parentheses to make it clear what is inside the log and what is not.  From here you just solve like you would any other linear equation for $x$ where $x$ is on both sides: move the $x$ terms to the same side, move the constants to the other, combine like terms and isolate $x$.